# Does this piece of code have potential to cause any problems in terms of memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I guess I am nervous that I am hiding the toolbar. Do I need to do any other de-allocation?

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];


        self.navigationItem.title = @"Add Recipients";

        self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=NO;


        UIBarButtonItem            *localItem;
        UIBarButtonItem            *remoteItem;


        localItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Local"
                                                       style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                      target: self
                                                      action: @selector( localRecipients: ) ];



        remoteItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Remote"
                                                        style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                       target: self
                                                       action: @selector( remoteRecipients: ) ];


        self.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: localItem,remoteItem,nil ];

        [localItem release];
        [remoteItem release];


    }


    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

        self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't require to do de-allocation because you are already taking care that in you code by releasing the both     `UIBarButtonItem`.

if you are retaining the `toolbarItems` ,Try with below code.

```
self.toolbarItems = nil ;
self.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: localItem,remoteItem,nil ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are responsible for releasing the objects you create. Since you did not create the toolbar you are not responsible for releasing it.